# Samsung Galaxy S10+ Will not boot into Recovery mode from Download Mode

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, boot-loop, odin, magisk

for the first time ever i'v tried to root my samsung device

I am running a Samsung Galaxy S10+ SM-G975F

I started by making sure OEM was unlocked + USB debugging put the phone into bootloader mode and unlocked it, then i proceeded to copy the AP firmware file across from my PC to the phone, Then used The Magisk Manager app to create the patched file, Copied this back over to my PC and flashed with ODIN v3.13

After the flash was complete for the root, the video i was watching mentioned you have to boot into recovery mode from download mode,

via

Hold Volume Down + Power button until the device restarts

Quickly Hold Volume Up + Bixby Button + Powerbutton, Until you see the bootloader warning flash then release all buttons except the Volume Up, until you boot into recovery mode.

Now I'v tried absolutely everything possible combination wise

Does anyone here have any solutions that may be of assistance as to me doing something incorrect?

the video i followed was this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3a8YnWT3yk

I can enter Download mode still with the Key Combinations, just i'm unable to reach Recovery mode with the combinations that are explained to use

Thank you.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after 2 years and existing answers have no votes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the S10 is that you cannot shut it down from "out of the Android OS".
Then you can only boot into the recovery with the (hard-ass) key combination when your phone is **completely shut down**. So if you miss the tricky key combination one time after shutdown or odin-flash you're stuck in some kind of boot loop between the "bootloader" and the "security warning". The only solution seems to be to let the battery drain so the phone is completely off and then use of one of the following methods:

> **Booting Into Different Modes**
>
> Even though you have rooted your Samsung Galaxy S10, you still have to
> keep in mind that both the recovery and the Magisk will be in the same
> partition. Which means that you will have to use a different method to
> root into the rooted system.
>
> Note: The following steps are to be followed **when your phone is
> completely powered off**.
>
> **Unrooted System**: Simply hold the power button as you would normally and your phone will boot into an unrooted system.
>
> **Rooted System**: Hold the Power, Bixby, and Volume Up buttons together, and release them once the Bootloader Warning screen appears
> and that will boot your phone into the rooted system.
>
> **Stock Recovery**: In order to do that, you will have to hold the Power, Bixby, and Volume Up buttons together, and release the Power
> and Bixby buttons when the Bootloader Warning screen appears and keep
> holding the Volume Up button to boot your device into the stock
> recovery.

In your case it will be the last option which is the most tricky key combination ever. I also failed it several times, it needs practice! (I suppose Samsung did this on purpose).

Check this guide, it's the best I found out there:
[Root Samsung S10 Guide](https://wccftech.com/how-to/root-samsung-galaxy-s10-magisk-root-unlock-bootloader/)